# Unable to activate changes in weblogic 12c

Tags: java, weblogic12c

After doing config changes when i am activating the changes in weblogic its thowing error as ...

<[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '44' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>  <>  <1559894426043> <[severity-value: 8] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name: DOMAIN] >

```
   at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.updateDeploymentContext(RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.java:1163)
   at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doUpdateDeploymentContextCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:155)
   at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.updateDeploymentContext(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:29)
   at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.ReceivedPrepare.callDeploymentReceivers(ReceivedPrepare.java:208)
   at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.ReceivedPrepare.handlePrepare(ReceivedPrepare.java:112)
   at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.statemachines.targetserver.ReceivedPrepare.receivedPrepare(ReceivedPrepare.java:52)
   at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.TargetRequestImpl.run(TargetRequestImpl.java:214)
   at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.transport.CommonMessageReceiver$1.run(CommonMessageReceiver.java:614)
   at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:678)
   at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
   at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
   at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
   at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
   at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
   at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
       at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToStream.(ToStream.java:144)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToXMLStream.(ToXMLStream.java:67)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.serializer.ToUnknownStream.(ToUnknownStream.java:143)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.runtime.output.TransletOutputHandlerFactory.getSerializationHandler(TransletOutputHandlerFactory.java:159)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.getOutputHandler(TransformerImpl.java:445)
       at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:328)
       at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ConfigReader.convert(ConfigReader.java:140)
       at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ConfigReader.(ConfigReader.java:70)
       at weblogic.management.provider.internal.ConfigReader.(ConfigReader.java:64)
       at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.handleConfigTreeLoad(RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.java:1630)
       at weblogic.management.provider.internal.RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService.updateDeploymentContext(RuntimeAccessDeploymentReceiverService

Comment: Please help here

Comment: Post the complete log message from weblogic server log file.